# How to edit elements in array of class type in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I edit a single element in array of a class type. For example how
can I assign a name and description for element 1?

Comment: Access it using the index. `myArr[1].SetName("x");`. You should read up on arrays though. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example your `object` here is of a `class` type `Car`. And your `Car object` has a method called `setNumberPlate(String x)` which is something like :

```
void setNumberPlate (String str)
{
   //numberPlate is a String data member of your Car class
   numberPlate = str;
}
```

The reason you need to have a method is because its a good practice to keep the data members of your `class` `private`. So, for example, here's the class :

```
Class Car
{
   private String numberPlate;

   public void setNumberPlate(String str)
   {
      numberPlate = str;
   }

}
```

Then you can access this method in another class.
If you store your objects in an `array`, then this is what you do.

`Car[] arr = new Car[10];`

`arr[0].setNumberPlate("UIA9490");`

Comment: You're very welcome. Give it a vote so that others know that its the right question.

Comment: just one more question can you please clarify how the numberplate member works?

Answer (score 0):

Object[] myArray = new Object7;
Object myObject = myArray[5]; // get object at index 5 then make changes to your object

Comment: I mean how you would get an object at the index and make changes to it

Comment: This line:  Object myObject = myArray[5]; gives you your object (in a variable called myObject). You can now change whatever you want. Substitute Object with whatever class your object is.

Comment: @user2870849:- How you would get means? You can directly specify the index of the arrays as myArray[index]

Comment: If this is HW, you should tag as HW

Comment: @WilliamFalcon last time I checked HW tag was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the array:

```
type[] arrayName = new type[size];
```

Example:

```
int[] someNumbers = new int[10]; // array with 10 slots
```

To get an element, simply use `arrayName[index]`. Arrays are `0-based`, so getting the 5th element is done by `someNumbers[4]`.

Let's say we have an array of Persons and you want to change a person address.

```
Person personObj = arrayOfPersons[3]; // get the 4th person
personObj.setAddress("New York");
```

That's it! You're done!

Additional notes:
You will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to access an element outside the array(using a negative index or an index greater or equal that the array length).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to add extra properties to this class?

I suppose you have an array

`String[] data = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}`

To add extra properties, may be you can try to create a wrapper:

```
class Wrapper<T> {

    private T origin

    public String name;
    public String desc

    public Wrapper(T data) {
        origin = data;
    }
}
```

To add extra properties:

```
Map<String, Wrapper> extraProperties = new HashMap<String, Wrapper>();

Wrapper<String> w = new Wrapper<String>(data[1]);
w.name = "a name";
w.desc = "description"

extraProperties.put(data[1], w);
```

To access the extra properties:

```
if(extraProperties.contains(data[1])) {
    extraProperties.get(data[1]).name
    extraProperties.get(data[1]).desc
}
```

Comment: Well, I think too much.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I assign a name and description for element 1?

That depends on your class, but here's a (bad) example:

```
YourClass[] array = .... ;           // wherever it comes from
array[1].name = "World";             // if name is a member of your class
array[1].setDescription("whatever"); // if there is a setter for description
```

Note that element 1 is the second element of the array as indeces start with 0.

Comment: Its not a good programming practice to keep class's data members private. That's why there need to be methods to modify the members.